# Loop through Range and use values on other method vba

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to achieve is to use values via a loop in another module.

My Excel file has 3 columns with each column 2 rows.
I want to use the values in each row (3 columns) inside an other method.

**My loop script**

```
Sub Loops()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("E1")
Set ws = Sheet1

Row = 1
    
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
   For Each cell In rng
    
        For icol = 1 To lCol
            For irow = 1 To lRow
            
                cell(Row).Value = ws.Cells(irow, icol)
                Row = Row + 1
            
            Next irow
        Next icol
    Next cell
  
End Sub
```

**Main Script**

```
Sub Main()
Dim text1 As String
Dim text2 As String
Dim text3 As String

text1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
text2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1")
text3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1")

Debug.Print text1; text2; text3

End Sub
```

As you can see in the **Main script** I have put in a hard link to the info that I need.
So I want to first get the values of row 1 (Columns A, B & C) and do something.
When this is done I want to get the values of row 2 (Columns A, B & C) and do something.

I want this to go through untill there are no more rows.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This is my excel file

[image]

So the **Main Script** should give as result

```
text1 = 1
text2 = 3
text3 = 5
```

When this is done the Main Script should run again. With result.

```
text1 = 2
text2 = 4
text3 = 6
```

And as there is no more row the script needs to stop.

Comment: I think it's better if you [edit] your question and post some sample data and try to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by "via a loop in another module"?

Comment: I don't see how I can explain it better. ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") in the Main script needs to be replaced but the values in the excel file and loop through all the different rows.

Comment: @FaneDuru Well that the main script get updated with the amount of rows in the excel file. So hard to explain if English isn't your language

Comment: Your first code does nothing. You try iterating in a range of a single cell (`Set rng = Range("E1")`). The second one does mean almost nothing. It is very difficult to understand what you want accomplishing... English is not my native language, too, but I cannot understand anything about your goal, sorry.

Comment: @FaneDuru let met try again. I want the value of  text1, text2 and text3 populated by the values on an other sheet. And if I have 2 rows of data on that sheet I want to repeat the process until there are no more rows with data. Better?

Comment: Still not clear. At least, for me. Do you want iterating between all rows of that "an other sheet" and extract all values of its columns, for the specific row? I mean firstly 'text1' to take the value of A1, and secondly the value of A2?

Comment: @FaneDuru I've updated my question. Yes that is what I want. First extract value of A1, B1 and C1. Than do the same again with the values of A2, B2 and C2

Comment: But there is no any connection between what you are saying now and "loop in another module"...

Comment: @FaneDuru maybe lost in translation. What I meant with loop is that it first needs to take A1, B1 and C1 and to something. Than when thats finish start the same process with A2, B2, C2

Comment: @GreenSquirrel check my answer below if that solves your question. I guess you mean the second part.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ no it doesn't. I need to first have the value of A1 and put in where now text1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") is in the Main Script. Than I need the value of B1 where now text2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1") is, and than I need the value of C1 where now text3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1") is. Once these 3 are completed It needs to restart but than with values A2, B2 and C2

Comment: Please tell what exactly you are trying to do with these 3 values (of a row) then, it does not make any sense. Everytime you number your variable names like `text1` this is a sign you do something fundamentally wrong. So please clarify and give a proper example of what you do with these values.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65669733/running-vba-script-with-multiple-urls-in-one-go?noredirect=1#comment116107489_65669733. And read the comment. This will make it all clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the same thing for every cell do something like this

```
Public Sub LoopingLouiCellWise()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow  'loop through all rows
        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 1 To LastCol  'loop through columns in this row
        
            'either put your entire code to do something here
            '…
            
            'or call a sub procedure
            DoSomethingWithCell ws.Cells(iRow, iCol)

        Next iCol
    Next iRow
End Sub


Private Sub DoSomethingWithCell(ByVal Cell As Range)
    'your code here
    Debug.Print Cell.Address
End Sub
```

---

If you want to do "something" with the entire row (row wise) then do something like this

```
Public Sub LoopingLouiRowWise()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow  'loop through all rows
            
        DoSomethingWithRow iRow, LastCol, ws

    Next iRow
End Sub


Private Sub DoSomethingWithRow(ByVal iRow As Long, ByVal LastCol As Long, ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    'your code here
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 To LastCol
        Debug.Print ws.Cells(iRow, iCol)
    Next iCol
End Sub
```

Note that in this version you need to tell your procedure in which worksheet `ws` you are working.